# Framer motion animating between two different words

Tags: typescript, framer-motion

I'm not sure if this is possible, but here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
<motion.div className="main-content" style={{ background }}>
      <motion.div
        className="circle"
        style={{ x }}
        drag="x"
        dragConstraints={{ left: 0, right: 0 }}
      />
      <div className="condition">
        <svg style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} viewBox="0 0 50 50">
          <motion.text x="10" y="40">
            {text}
          </motion.text>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </motion.div>
```

I'd like to animate between the following words:

"clear", "sunny", "cloudy"

And my approach is the same as I've done with the background (which works):

```
  const x = useMotionValue(0);
  const xInput = [0, 400, 800]; 
  const current = useTransform(x, [0, 200, 400], [1, 0, 0]);
  const threeHours = useTransform(x, [400, 600, 800], [0, 1, 0]);
  const sixHours = useTransform(x, [800, 1000], [0, 1]);

  const background = useTransform(x, xInput, [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "yellow"
  ]);

  const text = useTransform(x, xInput, [
    "clear",
    "sunny",
    "cloudy",
  ]);
```

The outcome is just the same value ("clear") across from 0 to 800 pixels on the x axis and I'd like it to change from clear to cloudy instead

Is this possible?